# Nativescript - tns create test app errors

Tags: javascript, java, android, linux, nativescript

I created a test app with "tns create test" but it errors when I try to run it. Error: "Unfortunately, test app has stopped."

Please advice what I'm missing!

Thanks in advance,
ami

--
Error log: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/9mf26a8hdwcl3b4/Screenshot%202016-06-06%2022.41.48.png?dl=0

Test app code:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/k8lkwoulh0k34ij/AAC7yTnMWIvGhWAF8lBQeUvra?dl=0

Command Logs:

```
# Ubuntu 16 LTS
# NODE, TNS, JAVA, ANDROID installed with: https://github.com/nraboy/ubuntu-nativescript-installer/blob/master/ubuntu_nativescript_installer.sh

dev@farm:~/test$ env
ANDROID_HOME=/opt/android-sdk
SHELL=/bin/bash
TERM=xterm
USER=dev
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/snap/bin:/opt/node/bin:/opt/android-sdk/tools:/opt/android-sdk/platform-tools:/opt/genymobile/genymotion
PWD=/home/dev/test
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java
NODE_HOME=/opt/node
......

dev@farm:~/test$ node --version
v4.4.5

dev@farm:~/test$ tns --version
2.0.1


dev@farm:~$ tns create test
Project test was successfully created.

dev@farm:~$ cd test
/home/dev/test

dev@farm:~/test$ tns install babel && tns platform add android
-
> nativescript-dev-babel@0.1.6 postinstall /home/dev/test/node_modules/nativescript-dev-babel
> node postinstall.js

babel-core@6.9.1 node_modules/babel-core
 babel-messages@6.8.0
 path-is-absolute@1.0.0
 slash@1.0.0
 babel-template@6.9.0
 shebang-regex@1.0.0
 path-exists@1.0.0
 babel-helpers@6.8.0
 private@0.1.6
 convert-source-map@1.2.0
 source-map@0.5.6
 babylon@6.8.1
 minimatch@2.0.10 (brace-expansion@1.1.4)
 debug@2.2.0 (ms@0.7.1)
 babel-types@6.9.1 (to-fast-properties@1.0.2, esutils@2.0.2)
 babel-code-frame@6.8.0 (js-tokens@1.0.3, esutils@2.0.2, chalk@1.1.3)
 babel-traverse@6.9.0 (globals@8.18.0, invariant@2.2.1)
 json5@0.4.0
 babel-generator@6.9.0 (detect-indent@3.0.1)
 lodash@4.13.1
 babel-register@6.9.0 (mkdirp@0.5.1, home-or-tmp@1.0.0, source-map-support@0.2.10, core-js@2.4.0)
 babel-runtime@6.9.2 (regenerator-runtime@0.9.5, core-js@2.4.0)
nativescript-dev-babel@0.1.6 node_modules/nativescript-dev-babel
 minimatch@3.0.0 (brace-expansion@1.1.4)
 glob@5.0.15 (path-is-absolute@1.0.0, inherits@2.0.1, inflight@1.0.5, once@1.3.3)
 nativescript-hook@0.2.1 (glob@6.0.4, mkdirp@0.5.1)
Copying template files...
  \u25e1 Installing tns-androidbabel-traverse@6.9.0 node_modules/babel-traverse
 babel-messages@6.8.0
 globals@8.18.0
 babylon@6.8.1
 debug@2.2.0 (ms@0.7.1)
 babel-types@6.9.1 (to-fast-properties@1.0.2, esutils@2.0.2)
 invariant@2.2.1 (loose-envify@1.2.0)
 babel-code-frame@6.8.0 (js-tokens@1.0.3, esutils@2.0.2, chalk@1.1.3)
 lodash@4.13.1
 babel-runtime@6.9.2 (regenerator-runtime@0.9.5, core-js@2.4.0)
   Installing tns-androidbabel-types@6.9.1 node_modules/babel-types
 to-fast-properties@1.0.2
 esutils@2.0.2
 lodash@4.13.1
 babel-runtime@6.9.2 (regenerator-runtime@0.9.5, core-js@2.4.0)
   Installing tns-androidbabylon@6.8.1 node_modules/babylon
 babel-runtime@6.9.2 (regenerator-runtime@0.9.5, core-js@2.4.0)
   Installing tns-androidfilewalker@0.1.2 node_modules/filewalker
 fqueue@0.0.0
   Installing tns-androidlazy@1.0.11 node_modules/lazy
Project successfully created.

dev@farm:~/test$ tns livesync android --watch --geny nexus5-emug
Successfully prepared plugin tns-core-modules for android.
Successfully prepared plugin tns-core-modules-widgets for android.
Project successfully prepared
Executing after-prepare hook from /home/dev/test/hooks/after-prepare/nativescript-dev-babel.js
Processing complete
Transferring project files...
Successfully transferred all project files.
Applying changes...
Successfully synced application org.nativescript.test on device 192.168.57.101:5555.
06-09 00:10:11.445   105   105 F DEBUG   :     #11 pc 00553d83  /data/app/org.nativescript.test-1/lib/x86/libNativeScript.so (v8::internal::RegExpImpl::CompileIrregexp(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSRegExp>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::String>, bool)+675)
06-09 00:10:11.445   105   105 F DEBUG   :     #12 pc 00553fd5  /data/app/org.nativescript.test-1/lib/x86/libNativeScript.so (v8::internal::RegExpImpl::IrregexpPrepare(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSRegExp>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::String>)+165)
06-09 00:10:11.445   105   105 F DEBUG   :     #13 pc 005544f3  /data/app/org.nativescript.test-1/lib/x86/libNativeScript.so (v8::internal::RegExpImpl::IrregexpExec(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSRegExp>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::String>, int, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSArray>)+51)
06-09 00:10:11.445   105   105 F DEBUG   :     #14 pc 005546a0  /data/app/org.nativescript.test-1/lib/x86/libNativeScript.so (v8::internal::RegExpImpl::Exec(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSRegExp>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::String>, int, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSArray>)+144)
```

Error! I uninstall app from geny and try this:

```
dev@farm:~/test$ tns platform remove android
Platform android successfully removed.

dev@farm:~/test$ tns platform add android
Copying template files...
Project successfully created.

dev@farm:~/test$ tns run android --watch --geny nexus5-emug
Successfully prepared plugin tns-core-modules for android.
Successfully prepared plugin tns-core-modules-widgets for android.
Project successfully prepared
Executing after-prepare hook from /home/dev/test/hooks/after-prepare/nativescript-dev-babel.js
Processing complete

:config phase:  createDefaultIncludeFiles
    +found plugins: tns-core-modules-widgets
     + creating include.gradle file for /home/dev/test/platforms/android/configurations/tns-core-modules-widgets
Renaming plugin directory to flavor name: /home/dev/test/platforms/android/src/tns-core-modules-widgets -> /home/dev/test/platforms/android/src/F0

:config phase:  createPluginsConfigFile
     Creating product flavors include.gradle file in /home/dev/test/platforms/android/configurations folder...

:config phase:  pluginExtend
    +applying configuration from: /home/dev/test/platforms/android/configurations/tns-core-modules-widgets/include.gradle
    +applying configuration from: /home/dev/test/platforms/android/configurations/include.gradle

:config phase:  copyAarDependencies

:config phase:  addAarDependencies
    +adding dependency: /home/dev/test/platforms/android/libs/aar/widgets-release.aar
:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:preF0DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:checkF0DebugManifest
:preF0ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2340Library
:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72340Library
:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42340Library
:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2340Library
:prepareWidgetsReleaseLibrary
:prepareF0DebugDependencies
:compileF0DebugAidl
:compileF0DebugRenderscript
:generateF0DebugBuildConfig
:cleanLocalAarFiles
:ensureMetadataOutDir
:collectAllJars
:setProperties
:asbg:generateInterfaceNamesList
:asbg:runAstParser
couldn't find logDirectory so it will be created in place:/home/dev/test/platforms/android/build-tools/android-static-binding-generator/ast-parser/logs/i.txt
inputDir: /home/dev/test/platforms/android/src/main/assets/app
outFile: ../bindings.txt
:asbg:generateBindings
:generateF0DebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:mergeF0DebugAssets
:generateF0DebugResValues
:generateF0DebugResources
:mergeF0DebugResources
:processF0DebugManifest
:processF0DebugResources
:generateF0DebugSources
:compileF0DebugJavaWithJavac
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
:compileF0DebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:compileF0DebugSources
:buildMetadata
 'assets/metadata/treeNodeStream.dat' NOT FOUND
 'assets/metadata/treeStringsStream.dat' NOT FOUND
 'assets/metadata/treeValueStream.dat' NOT FOUND
 'assets/metadata/treeNodeStream.dat'...
 'assets/metadata/treeStringsStream.dat'...
 'assets/metadata/treeValueStream.dat'...
:transformClassesWithDexForF0Debug
:mergeF0DebugJniLibFolders
:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForF0Debug
:processF0DebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForF0Debug
:validateDebugSigning
:packageF0Debug
:zipalignF0Debug
:assembleF0Debug
:assembleDebug
:deleteExplodedAarFolder
:buildapk

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 39.405 secs

This build could be faster, please consider using the Gradle Daemon: https://docs.gradle.org/2.8/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Project successfully built
Successfully deployed on device with identifier '192.168.57.101:5555'.
06-09 11:29:39.549   105   105 F DEBUG   :     #11 pc 00553d83  /data/app/org.nativescript.test-1/lib/x86/libNativeScript.so (v8::internal::RegExpImpl::CompileIrregexp(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSRegExp>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::String>, bool)+675)
06-09 11:29:39.549   105   105 F DEBUG   :     #12 pc 00553fd5  /data/app/org.nativescript.test-1/lib/x86/libNativeScript.so (v8::internal::RegExpImpl::IrregexpPrepare(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSRegExp>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::String>)+165)
06-09 11:29:39.549   105   105 F DEBUG   :     #13 pc 005544f3  /data/app/org.nativescript.test-1/lib/x86/libNativeScript.so (v8::internal::RegExpImpl::IrregexpExec(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSRegExp>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::String>, int, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSArray>)+51)
06-09 11:29:39.549   105   105 F DEBUG   :     #14 pc 005546a0  /data/app/org.nativescript.test-1/lib/x86/libNativeScript.so (v8::internal::RegExpImpl::Exec(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSRegExp>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::String>, int, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSArray>)+144)
```

Error!

Comment: try command - "tns doctor" (To check all files are installed properly or not)

Comment: it reports: "No issues were detected."

Comment: i don't think there is issue in your code. It is default code like "Hello world". Try to uninstall your app from genymotion. and then try command - "tns run android"

Comment: If you are running your app first time then you should use "tns run android". It will build your app modules and then you can use "tns livesync android".

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. I: uninstalled app from geny, tns platform remove android, add it back, run. This time run command worked more and showed info. on console but app errored again ith same mesg. https://www.dropbox.com/s/9mf26a8hdwcl3b4/Screenshot%202016-06-06%2022.41.48.png?dl=0

Comment: I had the same kind of problem on an existing app, in order to fix that,  i added an "applicationId" in the build.gradle file inside the defaultConfig { }

Comment: @Kansen Please describe more. What exactly did you add in the file?

Comment: @ami was my answer good enough for you ? Or you still have some troubles ?

Answer (score 0):

In your rootFolder/platforms/android you have a build.gradle file :
In this file (which is generated) you should have a "defaultConfig" property which might look like this :

`android {
...
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion computeTargetSdkVersion()
    }
...
}`

Update this code and add an "applicationId" property 

`defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion computeTargetSdkVersion()
        applicationId "com.stackoverflow.yourpackage"
    }`

By the way , this is how i fixed this but i have no idea why this generated file needs to be manually updated